# Error - 3012 : The program expected this account to be already initialized

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, nft

**Updated:**

I am encountering an issue while breeding the NFT. The NFT address and generation have been successfully created, but during the minting process, I encountered an error - **Error: 0xbc4**.
I am using a GitHub repository for NFT breeding.
https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding/blob/master/ts/utils.ts

Address: https://solscan.io/account/9tiP8yZcekzfGzSBmp7n9LaDHRjxP2w7wJj8tpPJtfG

this error is related to the address used during the transaction. Is there a way to investigate this address, understand its purpose, and determine why it is causing the issue during minting? Below are the instructions I received:

```
instructions: [
    TransactionInstruction {
      keys: [Array],
      programId: [PublicKey [PublicKey(2hUnrFc6x3BjANVrNW4RHcrwof7ogY7ZCbv9Tf44TmTN)]],
      data: <Buffer 33 39 e1 2f b6 92 89 a6>
    },
    TransactionInstruction {
      keys: [Array],
      programId: [PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)]],
      data: <Buffer 07 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
    },
    TransactionInstruction {
      keys: [Array],
      programId: [PublicKey [PublicKey(2hUnrFc6x3BjANVrNW4RHcrwof7ogY7ZCbv9Tf44TmTN)]],
      data: <Buffer 33 39 e1 2f b6 92 89 a6>
    }
  ],
  recentBlockhash: 'C9PvtjjFAs7uqE6Ew4W4Ly3P8cQ9uDLQDpM6dgwfJMbr',
  lastValidBlockHeight: undefined,
  nonceInfo: undefined,
  minNonceContextSlot: undefined,
  _message: undefined,
  _json: undefined
}
```

My deployed Program_ID : **2hUnrFc6x3BjANVrNW4RHcrwof7ogY7ZCbv9Tf44TmTN**

Answer (score 2):

in the first instruction, data seems to be empty. It should at least (if there is no args to your instruction) contains 8 bytes which tells to the program which instruction you are calling

EDIT: after checking the docs, data seems to be optionnal. But then i don't understand how the program is supposed to know which instruction is called, except if there is some kind of fallback or only one transaction ? i will let other people with more knowledge reply to the original question !

Comment: ```
   return new TransactionInstruction({
      keys,
      programId: ATA_INIT_PROGRAM_ID,
    });
 const ATA_INIT_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
    "2hUnrFc6x3BjANVrNW4RHcrwof7ogY7ZCbv9Tf44TmTN"
  );
```

Comment: The instructions I used, but still got empty data.

Comment: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/TransactionInstruction.html you're missing the data i think

Comment: I'm using createATAWithoutCheckIx function from -->

https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding/blob/master/ts/utils.ts